# My screen is blinking at 1920x1080

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, dvi

One of my monitors is HP 2211x and hes working perfectly using 1920x1080 resolution. But the problem is that ive bought today LG flatron W2243s and it seems that i cant get him to work at 1920x1080 resolution, image starts to blink (turn on and off) every 0.5 sec or so. Though it is working perfectly fine at 1680x1050, ive tried changing refresh rate but its not helping at all. HP is connect DVI-DVI and LG is connected via VGA-DVI adapter. And windows is kinda not detecting him since in device manager it says Generic PnP Monitor, but when i open screen resolution tab its listed there as W2243S. Btw, i'm using windows 8.

Comment: Can you confirm the exact  model? W2243S-PF? Should be on a sticker on the back of the panel.

Comment: @AthomSfere Yep, W2243S-PF

Comment: Swap the monitors and see what happens, that monitor's native mode is 1920*1080 so the behavior is odd.

Comment: Uhm i switched back from 1680 to 1920 on my 2nd monitor and it stayed like that without blinking, dunno why's working to be honest...

Comment: Actually its not fixed, now it blinks every 2 minutes or so >.<

Comment: I'd say it's a bad monitor. Just purchased it? Call LG or the vendor. The fact that it does that at native resolution on either port suggests a bad monitor and not cable, setting, videocard etc..